# Edit Windows Explorer context menu item description

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, context-menu, windows-10-preview, malwarebytes

Currently I have the following type of Explorer context menu for Malwarebytes.

I'd like to change the Finnish description to English (not [allowed](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/144976-context-menu-entry-in-a-different-language/) in the app), but searching the registry for "*Tarkista*" doesn't reveal a single result.

[image: Boo]

How is the description generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context menu item was added by MBAM's shell extension (`C:\Program Files\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware\mbamext.dll`).
This DLL contains hard-coded strings for every supported language and displays one according to default system language (because the shell extension is loaded inside of `explorer.exe`).

You should ask the vendor to *fix* this shell extension, so that it will use language selected in MBAM's settings.

The other option is to edit the string directly in *mbamext.dll* using a hex-editor. Though I don't recommend that as it will break file's digital signature.